# why can't I use partial struct initialization for a malloced struct in C

Tags: c, struct, alloc

Apperently in C99 you can simply initialize a statically allocated struct in this way

```
struct sometype {
   int a;
   double b;
};
sometype a = {
   .a = 0;
};
```

Well, this does not apply to a struct on heap like this.

```
struct sometype *a = malloc(sizeof(struct sometype));
*a = {
   .a = 0;
 };
```

With GCC 4.9.2, the compiler complained

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
```

I know this is silly, but is there any syntax or technical reason that I cannot do this?

Comment: Where is the malloc that you promised? And you realise that there is no type named sometype? There is only a struct sometype, not a sometype.

Comment: @gnasher729 Well, that was just a illustration, I wasn't so carefull on that, since the second piece code was important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between struct initialization, and assignment.

When using heap memory, it's always assignment, since initialization only happens when you're actually declaring the instance (not just a pointer to an instance).

You can use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.3/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
struct sometype *ms = malloc(sizeof *ms);
*ms = ((struct sometype) { .a = 0 });
```

But of course this might be worse than just doing:

```
ms->a = 0;
```

since it will write to *all* fields of the structure, setting all the fields that weren't mentioned in the literal to zero. Depending on what you need, this can be needlessly costly.

Comment: Your last sentence isn't true. If a subobject is missing in an initializer list, it will be initialized implicitly to the (non-random) default value (see the C99 spec, 6.7.8.19). So `*ms = ((struct sometype) { .a = 0 })` will set `ms->b` to `0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

> Well, this does not apply to a struct on heap.

Yes. It will not. That's because there is a difference in *initialization* and *assignment*. In case of

```
sometype a = {.a =0};
```

this is initialization. In case of dynamic allocation

```
sometype *a = malloc(sizeof(struct sometype);
*a = {.a =0};
```

there is assignment.