# Partially initializing a C struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization, variable-assignment

This [link](http://c-faq.com/decl/initval.html) states that "When an automatic array or structure has a partial initializer, the remainder is initialized to 0". I decided to try out what I read and wrote the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    //int arr[3] = {2};  // line no. 7

    struct s {
        int si;
        int sj;
    };

    struct s myStruct;
    myStruct.si = 9;
    printf("%d\n", myStruct.sj);
}
```

I don't understand why `4096` (which I believe is some "garbage" value) is printed when I comment out `line no. 7` and I get `0` when I uncomment `line no. 7`. I don't think the `arr` declaration has got something to do with `main()`'s activation record (or rather `myStruct`) which should look like (provided we have `line no. 7` uncommented):

```
---------------
|  Saved PC   |
---------------
|  arr[2]     |
---------------
|  arr[1]     |
---------------
|  arr[0]     |
---------------
|  si         |
---------------
|  sj         |
---------------
```

Can somebody please explain what I am missing here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28545491/694576

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When you do this:

```
struct s myStruct;
myStruct.si = 9;
```

You are not *initializing* `myStruct`.  You declare it *without an initializer*, then run a statement to set one field.

Because the variable is uninitialized, its contents are undefined, and reading it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means that seemingly unrelated changes can modify this behavior.  In your example adding an extra variable *happened* to cause `myStruct.sj` to be 0, but there's no guarantee that this will be the case.

To *initialize* a variable, you have to give it a value at the time it is *defined*:

```
struct s myStuct = { 9 };
```

One you do this, then you'll see the contents of `myStruct.sj` set to 0.  This is guaranteed as per section 6.7.8 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (with highlighting specific to this case):

> 10 If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized  explicitly, its  value  is indeterminate.   **If an  object
> that  has  static  storage  duration  is  not  initialized
> explicitly**, then:
>
> —if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null
> pointer;
>
> —**if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;**
>
> —**if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized
> (recursively) according to these rules;**
>
> —if it is a union, the first
> named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.
>
> ...
>
> 21 **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there
> are  elements  in  the  array, **the  remainder  of  the  aggregate
> shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static
> storage duration.**

Comment: `declare it without an initializer` is a nice way to put it.. As a side note none of the answers yet have explained `I get 0 when I uncomment line no. 7`

Comment: Compiler options can be set to initialize all memory to zero and some operating systems may do so, but `myStruct.sj` could be anything as @dbush points out. If `myStruct.sj` is a pointer than the uninitialized value could cause all kinds of trouble, this has happened to me.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin : Without compliler options set, could you give an example for `some operating systems that do so`. I believe both Linux and Windows will not do so..

Comment: In relation to "_I get 0 when I uncomment line no. 7_": As dbush notes ("_seemingly unrelated changes ... adding an extra variable happened to cause myStruct.sj to be 0_"), by definition, it is undefined, in _plausible practice_ it is whatever happens to have been left in that bit of memory.  If you were to vary the size of your `arr[3]` definition (thus varying how far down memory the `si` and `sj` in your memory map are), you _may_ get a whole range of values.

Comment: @sjsam I know some memory chips that tend to do so.  Alternating 1s and 0s is another common pattern.  None of this is something you can rely on unless you write code to do it.  Undefined behaviour in C and C++ means anything can happen.  It is that way because defining it would be more work for the compiler/processor and if you want it done you can ask by programming it to do so.

Comment: With `myStruct.si = 9;` did you mean sj, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Spotlight That's what OP originally had.  He set `si` and, thinking it was an initialization, expected `sj` to be 0.

Comment: @dbush Ah, okay. Looking at it again I didn't see the difference between sj and si. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-referenced this handy answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900970/how-to-init-struct-pointer-variables-with-null/59930302#59930302

Answer (score 15):

In your case,

```
 myStruct.si = 9;
```

is an **[assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))** statement, **not** **[initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming))**. In this case, the structure variable (and the corresponding variables) are uninitialized. Thus, you're ending up reading the value of an uninitialized variable `sj`, which leads to  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can try

```
struct s myStruct = {9};
```

to see the *implicit initialization* in action.

Answer (score 11):

That's not an initializer -- your structure is uninitialized, then you assign  only `si`. `sj` remains uninitialized.

The book is referring to this kind of code:

```
struct s myStruct = {9};
```

... where `sj` is guaranteed to be 0.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a - more-or-less- complete example for the great answers others already gave.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct{
  int a;
  int b;
}obj1={.a=0}; //Partial initialization

typedef struct struct_B{
  int a;
  int b;
}struct_B;

int main(void)
{
  printf("obj1.b : %d\n",obj1.b);
  struct_B obj2={.b=1,.a=0,0}; // b's first value is overridden here as 0 immediately follows a
  printf("obj2.b : %d\n",obj2.b);
  struct_B obj3={0}; //Partial initialization, here the '0' value is meant for a as it comes first in the declaration
  printf("obj3.b : %d\n",obj3.b);
  struct_B obj4={.a=0}; //Partial initialization
  printf("obj4.b : %d\n",obj4.b);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
obj1.b : 0
obj2.b : 0
obj3.b : 0
obj4.b : 0
```