# write() and read() functions not working properly

Tags: c

I am trying to write a struct to a `.dat` file and when I open it it shows me this:

> "1^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@041720881^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Denko^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Brenko^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@13.07.2000^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
> "

It adds random symbols between the actual values. And now when I at least try to read and print some values, it just doesn't work. It's like the buffer is empty. But I followed the instructions and guides I read.

Using `fwrite` or similar is not an option since I have to work with these specific functions `write()` and `read()`.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct info{
    char id[20];
    char telefon[20];
    char ime[20];
    char priimek[20];
    char datum[20];
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct info dude =
            {
                "01",
                "041720881",
                "Denko",
                "Brenko",
                "13.07.2000"
    };

    struct info dude2 =
            {
                "02",
                "041581734",
                "Denko",
                "Badenko",
                "13.07.1990"
            };

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0){

        int fd = open("xpo.dat", O_CREAT| O_APPEND | S_IRWXG, 0666);
        if(fd == -1){
            perror("Error while creating file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-o") == 0){
        struct stat sizefile;

        int fd = open("xpo.dat", O_RDWR);
        if(fd == -1){
            perror("Error while opening file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }       
        fstat(fd,&sizefile);
        int wr = write(fd, &dude,sizeof(struct info));

        char buf[101];
        int sz = read(fd, buf, 100);
        buf[sz] = '\0';
        if(sz == -1) {
            perror("Error while creating file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("%s", buf);
        int cl = close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re "*It adds random symbols between the actual values*", No, nothing is added. You are printing `dude.id[0]` (`'0'`) followed by `dude.id[1]` (`'1'`) followed by `dude.id[2]`  (`0`, shows as `^@`), followed by `dude.id[3]` (`0`, shows as `^@`), ... And that's exactly what you get. What did you want to print?

Comment: What about the read() not working? I just wanted to print the whole struct that was written in file

Comment: You cannot use `write` and `read` one right after another.

Comment: So I would need to close the file after writing and then opening it again for reading?

Comment: `buf[sz] = '\0'; if(sz == -1) {`  That check comes too late.  If `sz == -1`, then trying to write to `buf[sz]` is undefined.  Do the check first, and don't write if sz < 0.

Comment: regarding: `if(strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0){`  Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected command line parameter.

Comment: "So I would need to close the file after writing and then opening it again for reading" You can also use `lseek` in between. My original statement was not entirely right, you can in general use `read` and `write` one after another, just not in this case, because the file position after a `write` is at the end of file, and `read` will return **zero** (which you should handle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `struct` contains 100 `char`s of data. But you are setting only some of them. When you set `ime` as `Denko`, the first six `char`s are set as `'D'`, `'e'`, `'n'`, `'k'`, `'o'`,`'\0'`. The remaining 14 are not initialized (or rather initialized implicitly, see [@dave_thompson_085's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924443/write-and-read-functions-not-working-properly/66924707#comment118302757_66924707)).

If you want to omit those `char`s, you cannot write the `struct` as one block. Either write each field separately, or concatenate the fields into a  string and write it instead.

Comment: They _are_ intialized, though not explicitly -- if an aggregate (array or struct) has a partial initializer, remaining elements or fields are initialized to zero (of the appropriate type) (as statics are for no initializer); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688971/c-char-array-initialization and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548287/partially-initializing-a-c-struct . OP might (or might not) want to avoid writing the _unneeded_ or _excess_ chars.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments and in the accepted answer, you have some issues, the why and the what is already talked about and explained.

I would like to add some more information:

> *And now when I at least try to read and print some values, it just doesn't work. It's like the buffer is empty.*

What happens is that you are reading from the end of the file, if you want to `read` after you `write` without closing and reopening the file, you can, but you'll need to reposition the offset of the opened file to the beginning using `lseek`.

Another thing to note is that if you want to write the data as a structure you then need to read it as a structure as well, not as a string.

Taking that in consideration your code could look more or less like this (skipping return value validations, but you should do it, as you know):

```
//...
else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-o") == 0){

    int fd = open("xpo.dat", O_RDWR);  
    int wr = write(fd, &dude, sizeof dude);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // set the reading position to the beginning of the file
    struct info buf;
    wr = read(fd, &buf, sizeof buf);
    int cl = close(fd);
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s", buf.id, buf.telefon, buf.ime, buf.priimek, buf.datum);
}
//...
```

If you prefer it as a string you can easily concatenate it using something like `snprintf` or similar.